# Cannot create Group List Settings View

Tags: 2010, list, groups

I have 2 site collections on different ports.

In site one with port 1234, I am able to create a new group and then add a couple of AD users to the group. Once done, I can click the `Settings` menu item and choose `List Settings`.  From here, I can create views.

On site collection two on port 80, I can do the same thing in the root but not in a sub-site. I don't have the `List Settings` option. I see `Group Settings`, `View Group Permissions` and `Make default group`.

`List Settings` is missing. I am sure there is a setting somewhere I am missing.

Comment: The sub-site, is it using `Unique` permissions?

Comment: Yes.  And there are a few folders with specific permissions as well.

Comment: @AmalHashim The minute you asked that very basic question, I rethought this and went to the root collection and to groups and More...  I found my group and it had List Settings there.

Comment: Sean: I added it as an answer. Hope it helps people with similar queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the sub-site in question don't have unique permission. All the group's will be available in the root.

You can open the `People & Groups` from the root site and make the changes you are trying.